# Registration issues with OSH park 4 layer boards?

Tags: pcb, eaglecad

I just got back a 4 layer board from oshpark and have a few shorts on the board (no components stuffed).  In particular I have two .050" pitch connectors with 4 pins each.  It appears as though all the pads of the connectors are shorted together.  The design passes DRC without issue and there are no overlaps anywhere.  One of the connectors has two pins that each have a single short trace on the top layer only.  Somehow these pins are shorted together (and to the surrounding pins).  My best guess is that there's a registration error with the internal layers such that somehow the connector is being shorted on one (or both) of them.  Has anyone had a similar issue with either oshpark or another fab shop?  I've looked carefully at the tow inner layers in eagle and cannot find anything obviously wrong (more importantly neither does the DRC).  Can you think of any other reasons why these pins are shorted?

[image]

Screen shots of the inner layer in Eagle for the area in question:

[image]

[image]

Comment: It's impossible to say without looking at the Gerbers.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that I just spent some time with the multimeter and noticed that every net with a via is shorted together regardless of whether that via is meant to touch an inner layer or not.  Seems like it's 99.99% a registration issue.  @MattAnderson I doubt it -- I'm using eagle so you don't really have an option to play with the pad stack.  The only way to really do that is play with the restring during DRC, but I left it at default values for the fab house.

Comment: @MattYoung oshpark lets you upload a .brd (which I did in this case).  I just put screenshots of the two inner layers in the original post.

Comment: You may be correct, but it bothers me that you are implicating OSH Park and it seems that you have not discussed this issue with them. If what you are suggesting is true then all of the boards on that run should be affected. OSH Park provides a very helpful service and I've built boards through them before. Just because _you_ can't think of any reason but alignment problems doesn't constitute convincing evidence to me.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about PCB fabrication quality issues from a specific vendor.

Comment: @JoeHass I think I *have* provided pretty decent evidence that there was a fab issue.  I have also very candidly asked for alternate explanations.  Nothing about my question is anti osh park.  I love osh park and use them all the time.  Given that I *do* use them regularly I was surprised to encounter this issue and, therefore, polled the forum for feedback.  My question was simply whether or not other people have encountered this kind of thing.

Comment: @JYelton my question specifically solicits feedback regarding similar issues from oshpark and any other fab shops.  I've never had this problem before so I'm trying to figure out what's going on.  It could be in the end that my theory is correct and it's a one off bug.  Maybe not though.  Maybe there are ways to mitigate these issues that are fab house agnostic.

Comment: Also it's worth keeping in mind that osh park isn't actually physically fabbing the these boards -- they provide an awesome service to aggregate boards and fab externally.  If there was a fabrication error it's not like they're to blame.

Comment: If the question had been asking for advice without mentioning a name the answers would be more fab agnostic without bias. If you mention a name it is interpreted as finger pointing even if it was not intented as such. Text is very poor at converying emotional context in this sort of situation. More usefull would have been. What were the fab asked and what were the reponses of the fab? (Without name dropping). I haven't used a fab directly in years but plan to do sosoon. I am very interested in the fault and it's resolution for the next run.

Comment: To use DRC passing as an argument, you need to post at least a summary of what they are.  Passing a 1mil clearance rule wouldn't mean much.  In any case, fabrication errors are not that uncommon, and that is why electrical tests are offered.

Comment: The problem is that it's difficult to come up with a definitive answer as to what went wrong. The only way to do that is to physically inspect the boards and communicate with the fab house. "Soliciting feedback" isn't what the StackExchange sites are designed for. They're designed to provide answers to questions. While responses here may provide insight and valuable feedback, nothing can be selected as "the" answer without the aforementioned inspection and fab house communication. I sympathize with the issue and would love to know the cause, but unfortunately this format is not ideal.